# Regex/Pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have the following list of part numbers from one of our vendors:

```
"3H0875AAAA0012"
"3H0875AABB0018"
"3H0875AAAC0010"
```

However, internally all of these part numbers are the same. I need to be able to compare the following part number: `"3H0875AA"` to the list above. Then the output should be three.

Something like:

```
stringB.matches(*stringA*); //where * means any character or characters before/after the string
```

The idea is that I can find all possible matches in a list of part numbers that contain the word `"3H0875AA"` in the string. I've tried to look into possible alternatives in regex but don't seem to understand it too good.

EDIT: The idea is to apply this concept to a large list of partNumbers. So I'm not sure on how to apply regex to a long list of partnumber rather than to a single partnumber as I mentioned in the example.

EDIT 2: Please see example below to confirm if its valid:

```
public void example(List<String> test, List<String> test2){

    for(String s: test){
        for (String s2: test2){
            if (s.matches("*."+s2+".*")){
                System.out.println("Match");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please advise

Comment: `(.*)(3H0875AA)(.*)` should work in an extremely crude sense

Comment: and let's say that I have a list of strings to compare can I do: (.*)stringA(.*) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the observation of your input, my suggestion will be to using this:

```
stringB.matches("3H0875AA.*");
```

But if you want to check the string to be anywhere, then you can use this:

```
stringB.matches(".*3H0875AA.*");
```

In the regex `.*` means any character(except `\n`) unlimited times.

Comment: Since OP seems not to understand regex too good consider adding some explanation of why this regex should work.

Comment: and can I apply the same concept to an input of strings? say like: stringB.matches(".*"+stringA+".*") ?

Comment: @WiloMaldonado Yes, you can do so. But it will be better if you use `java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(stringA)` instead of only `stringA` to escape regex characters.

Comment: @SabujHassan - Please see my additional EDIT above where I added the Java code. Basically that is what I want to do.

Comment: @WiloMaldonado `+java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(s2)+`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string `stringA` containing your part number, you can use `matches` on it like this:

```
stringB.matches(".*" + Pattern.quote(stringA) + ".*");
```

The reason for `Pattern.quote` is that certain characters are special characters in a regular expression, and `Pattern.quote` adds extra commands to the regex to make sure those characters are *not* treated as special.  Letters and digits aren't special, though, so if you *know* that `stringA` contains only letters and digits, you can skip `Pattern.quote`:

```
stringB.matches(".*" + stringA + ".*");
```

If you have multiple strings that you want to check against, you could loop do the above match one part number at a time.  Or you can join them all together like this:

```
stringB.matches(".*(3H0875AA|3J1127XQ|4X0078BA).*");
```

which will check for any of those part numbers.  If you have an array of those strings, you can do this in Java 8:

```
String[] partNumbers;

stringB.matches(".*(" + String.join("|", partNumbers) + ").*");
```

if all the part numbers contain only letters and digits.  Or you can use a stream to use `Pattern.quote` and join everything together with `|`:

```
stringB.matches(".*(" + Arrays.stream(partNumbers).map(Pattern::quote).collect(Collectors.joining("|")) + ").*");
```

Or in Java 7 you can construct a string using `StringBuilder` and using a loop to append all the part numbers with `Pattern.quote` and insert `|` between the parts.